# Dúvida diretório xampp

Tags: xampp

Possuo uma dúvida referente ao xampp.

Tenho uma pasta no htdocs dentro do diretorio do xampp.

**A dúvida é a seguinte:**

Quando eu acesso essa pasta pela web por exemplo: *https://localhost/minhapasta* não carrega nem um JS na página. Porém quando acesso direto assim : ***localhost/minhapasta*** carrega normalmente.

Por que acontece isso ? E como remediar ?

Comment: Olha o primeiro exemplo é http**s** o segundo só http.

Comment: Sim, só que possou mais de uma pasta dentro do **htdocs**, ai quando vou entrar em outra por exemplo **localhost/minhapasta2** ele vai direto para a "minhapasta". Ai se eu por o *https://* na frente ele vai para a "minhapasta2" só que não carrega nem um JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontrei a solução no [Stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp) (porque no uso o Xampp) e traduzi-o livremente:

"Encontre o arquivo "httpd-ssl.conf", abaixo do comentário "SSL Virtual Host Context", o que está sob a porta 443 (https), é procurado em um diretório diferente, então simplesmente altere o "document root" para o mesmo diretório e o problema será resolvido."